# DynDNS updater?

Tags: dyndns

Back in Windows, I had a DynDNS updater which showed a little icon in the task bar... It was a launch-and-forget little app. I want to know if there is something similar in Ubuntu.

Specifically, I'd like to have some kind of notification applet which shows status, that is, whether IP is currently updated or not.

Is there anything like that? Or should I stick to command-line-only apps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I would configure my home router to handle all DynDNS management. It is the proper place to deal with the task of setting correctly your IP address.
For more on configuring your router with DynDNS see http://www.dyndns.com/support/clients/hardware/

Comment: My router is not in the certified list.... nor in the non-certified list. BUT I have cheked the router's web interface and there's a DynDNS config page!!... I'll check that and mark your answer if it works. The only drawback is that I won't have a visual indicator....

Comment: Well it simply works... There's still the lack of a "visual cue" that everything's ok, but provided Martin's solution shows the same lack, I'll accept yours (even though I thank him for his).

Answer (score 3):

I can find only command line apps. But it wouldn't be hard to build an indicator for what you want to do:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators

Comment: Ty.. but it's too much for me... at least for now :)

Answer (score 2):

Years ago I the DynDNS updater version 3.1.0.15 through Wine. We no longer support that version of the updater, so keep that in mind. It may be worth a shot to try our newest update client through Wine as well.

Chris Widner 
Director of Community, Culture & Customers 
http://www.dyn.com

Comment: Thank you for your answer... I'm glad someone from Dyn took the time to answer here. On a side note I'm trying to step out of wine as much as I can.