# Port won't open!

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, firewall, iptables

I have a server that want to allow connections into it through port 25565, but when I test on http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ it says they are closed?

I have no outfacing interface configured either

My router has ports 25565 open, and these are my iptables rules

```
$ iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:webmin
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:25565
           all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination    

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             94.5.56.101          tcp to:192.168.0.8

$ iptables -t nat -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Comment: If you have "no outfacing interface" how do you expect the outside (that yougetsignal.com site) to be able to connect to diagnose your system?

Comment: Thanks, update: I set a rule so that traffic coming into my external IP is forwarded to my ipv4 address. But I still can't listen on the port!

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/427645/how-to-map-my-ipv4-address-to-external-address-in-iptables/427654#427654

Comment: My router handles my external IP forwarding by using DynDns to resolve it if my address ever changes the ports I forwarded won't